# Kundera Ehcache not working

Tags: orm, nosql, ehcache, kundera

I am running Kundera 2.8.1 . when i'm configuring ehcache in my persistence.xml its not being picked up. I have a ehcache-test.xml file configured in my classpath. On inspecting i'm finding that Kundera is not picking up the properties from persistence.xml.

In the constructor for EntityManagerFactoryImpl the Map properties is null.
Is this a bug in this release?

Answer (score 1):

Did you define

1. `<property name="kundera.cache.provider.class"
               value="com.impetus.kundera.cache.ehcache.EhCacheProvider" />`
2. `<property name="kundera.cache.config.resource" value="/ehcache-test.xml" />`

Comment: Could you please raise it on github { https://github.com/impetus-opensource/Kundera/issues }

Comment: This has been fixed and releasing with 2.9.1

Comment: @vivekmishra I am having an issue in which I am not able to connect Cassandra db from my Play! framework application. I am using Cassandra 2.2 and Play! 2.4 versions respectively. Can I ask you for your help regarding configuration of Kundera for connecting with cassandra databases ? It would be glad to have a chat on Gtalk or something for this ?

Comment: drop an email at kundera@impetus.co.in. looks like you missing on some configurations.